# why & how are BFS nodes goal tested when they are generated?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

In BFS, nodes are goal tested when they are generated.In other searches, nodes are goal tested before expanding them.what is the difference between this two statements? What is the advantage from this?

Comment: You seem to be asking a *purely theoretical* question about algorithms. such questions are better asked on [Computer Science.SE site](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

A Breadth-First Search (BFS) uses a queue of nodes to process. A Depth-First Search (DFS) for comparison can be written similarly using a stack.

When a node is expanded, all adjacent unvisited nodes are added to the queue (or stack).

When a node is goal tested, the algorithm is checking if the node has some desired property and should return the node rather than continue searching.

Note this is a search, which stops once a desired node is found, rather than a traversal, which always visits all reachable nodes.

BFS goal checks before adding new nodes to the queue. BFS expands nodes after extracting them from the queue.

BFS can goal test before adding to the queue for efficiency reasons. In the case of the BFS, you traverse outward from the root node looking for a goal node. If you've found the goal (or a goal, if it's not unique), there is no need to search further to the adjacent nodes. If you are goal testing before adding nodes to the queue, it also means none of the nodes already in the queue are the goal. Looking at it another way, if you had instead goal tested when extracting nodes from the queue, you will not extract a goal node from the queue before the point the first goal node is added. By this reasoning, whether you goal test when you insert a node to the queue, or goal test when you extract the node from the queue, you should end up finding the same node. The difference is by goal testing first, you don't have to process all the nodes already in the queue before returning the goal node.